# Property File Not Accessible from Jar built using Maven but working fine in eclipse?

Tags: java, command-prompt, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin, properties-file

I know people already asked similar questions but I tried all the suggestions given in other posts but didn't succeed. Hence posting my question:

I have a maven project with the configuration below:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>      
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>        
    </properties>

    <build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <index>true</index>
        <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.test.tools.services.Sample</mainClass>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>            
      </archive> 
     <excludes>
        <exclude>config.properties</exclude>
        <exclude>logback.xml</exclude>
     </excludes>         
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/windows.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now my project structure is default maven project given below:

```
    src
      |main
          java
             com
                test
                    tools
                         utils
                             Utility.java

      |resources
          config.properties
```

The maven build is making the zip file with the below structure:

```
target
   |project.zip
         |config
             config.properties
         |lib
            main.jar
            dependency.jar
```

The windows.xml defines the following:

```
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <outputDirectory>config</outputDirectory>           
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Inside the Utility.java I am accessing the property file as shown below:

```
InputStream input = Utility.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

The above code works fine when I run it in eclipse but the moment I run it on command prompt, I get File Not Found Exception.

Please provide any pointer/solution.

Thanks in advance.
`

Comment: Just try  ```Reader configReader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));```

Comment: You're doing something very wrong here, which is to have one properties file both inside the JAR and outside of it. The one outside will be completely ignored and will fool everyone into thinking it's useful. Apart from that, the comment above will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, and yes you are right I don't want my property file inside the jar which I have removed by adding <exclude> tags.

Now I have 1 property file outside the jar and inside the config folder present at the same level of folder "lib".

Tried 
Reader configReader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));

but its not working to access the property file present outside the jar.
Could you provide the option for that too? and it would be really  great if you can explain in brief that how exactly it looks for the file path.

Thanks

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Its giving Null Pointer Exception, basically it is not getting the config.properties.

Comment: Could anyone please help, I have tried many options with no luck.

Also tried       <manifestEntries>              
        <Class-Path>/config</Class-Path>
      </manifestEntries>